# Why doesn't this PHP work as expected in xampp?

Tags: php, html, xampp

I'm sure I'm missing something very obvious here. I create the below php file and loaded it in xampp with apache running. I would expect it to print 'hello' 5 times. Instead the page is blank, and the if I inspect the page elements in chrome, I see the PHP as commented out, as shown in the below image.

```
<?
for($i = 0; $i < 5; $i++) {
    echo 'hello';
}
?>
```

[image]

Comment: Short open tags my friend short open tags :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace your code as

```
<?php
for($i = 0; $i < 5; $i++) {
    echo 'hello';
}
?>
```

If you are using short tags, then it must be configured in your config file. Too set short tags add

```
short_open_tag=On
```

in **php.ini**

And restart your Apache server.

Comment: thanks, the typo was actually just in typing it into SO. issue was the opening tag. didn't realize I couldn't use short tags. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, use the `<?php` opening tag. `<?` may have been disabled.

Secondly, syntax error in your for loop. You're missing a `$` for `i++`.

Answer (score 0):

you missed $ in for loop its $i not i
the correct one is shown below...hope this solves

```
for($i = 0; $i < 5; $i++) { <br>
    echo 'hello'; <br>
}
```